# Crawling html using Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

```
#searchMenu > div.menu_wrap > ul > li.first.actived > div > div > div > 
div.menu_con.ng-scope > ul > li.actived > div > div.result_list > div > ul 
> li:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
```

So I want to extract all elements like this.

```
li:nth-child(1) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
li:nth-child(2) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
li:nth-child(3) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
li:nth-child(4) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
li:nth-child(5) > ul > li:nth-child(3)
```

How can I make code using 'for loop'?

I just tried this code:

```
address = [] 

for book in tags: 
    tag = book.select_one('li:nth-of-type(4) ').text address.append(tag)
    print(address)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  What happened?

Comment: I just tried this code.

        address = []
        for book  in tags:
            tag = book.select_one('li:nth-of-type(4) ').text
            address.append(tag)
        
        print(address)

Comment: can you provide actual HTML code of whole div?

Comment: You can use the [edit] button to make improvements to your question and add more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Enumerate the tags and pass the index value to your selector. Like this,

```
for i, book in enumerate(tags): 
    tag = book.select_one('li:nth-of-type('+str(i)+') ').text address.append(tag)
    print(address)
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!

Comment: Do a upvote and accept if my answer provided solution for your question. This is the ethic in SO.